# 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: c#, winforms

I have simple application like "paint", I draw in a bitmap which is set to the `pictureBox.Image`. I can draw here polygons and catch them on the vertices and move, so the bitmap must be repaint.
There is the repaint method.

```
private void DrawFullList()
    {
        if(pictureBox2.Image != null)
            pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
        graphic = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height); // exception here
        g = Graphics.FromImage(graphic);
        pictureBox2.Image = graphic;
        for (int i = 0; i < PointsList.Count; i++)
        {
            bool yellowframe = false;
            if (i == dblclck)
                yellowframe = true;
            Draw(BrushList[i], PointsList[i], yellowframe);
        }
    }
```

So if I catch vertice and move mouse, the function `DrawFullList()` is activated in the `pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` function. When I move the one vertice for few second (for example, making circles) The exception `'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll` is thrown.
Any tips here? :)

Edit:
additional info about exception:
`parameter is invalid`

Comment: Is there a specific message that accompanies it?

Comment: parameter is invalid

Comment: What is the invalid value's value?  Are you breaking on exceptions?  Interrogate the value to see what it doesn't like.

Comment: width = 1328, height = 1162;
but the size of bitmap does not change during the moving vertice, and it's creating correctly for few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should dispose from g - `g.dispose()` to free memory. Lack of memory can cause such a exception because your bmp may be too big for actually free memory.

Comment: Thank you! it works for me. Spent much time to find the solution, thought if I free image from picturebox, this will be also free :))